# ImportError: No module named xxxxx

Tags: python-3.x, import

I know this question has already been asked several times on the site, but I have not seen any satisfactory answer. I have a project partitionned like this

```
TLS project (folder)
sniffer_tls.py
| - tls (folder)
     | - __init__.py
     | - tls_1_2.py
         | - handshake (folder)
             | --__ Init__.py
             | - client_hello.py
```

when I am importing tls_1_2.py sniffer_tls.py in the main file, there is no problem. By cons when I import client_hello in tls_1_2.py, there python that mistake me out

```
File "/home/kevin/Documents/Python/Projet TLS/tls/tls_1_2.py", line 8, in 
    import handshake.client_hello
ImportError: No module named 'handshake'
```

I tried to import this way
`import handshake.client_hello`
and then I tried another way that I read on the forum
`import client_hello from handshake.client_hello`
I deleted the **init**.py file to test, it does not work either, I really need help to solve this problem

Comment: Eddit: i'm using python3.5

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a typo in your "handshake" `__init__.py` file. Instead you've named it `__Init__.py` with capital 'I'